# AccessDeniedError while trying connect to remote RabbitMQ server

Tags: python, rabbitmq, rpc, pika

I'am trying to connect two hosts with RabbitMQ & python pika.

Here is worker:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika, time
NEW_TASK_HOST_IP = '192.168.0.2'
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('login-to-remote', 'pass')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
                    pika.ConnectionParameters(host=NEW_TASK_HOST_IP))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue', durable=True)
print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='task_queue')
```

And here is new task:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika, sys
WORKER_IP = '192.168.0.3'
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('login-to-remote', 'pass')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host=WORKER_IP, socket_timeout=300, credentials=credentials))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue', durable=True)

message = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]) or "Hello World!"
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='task_queue',
                      body=message,
                      properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                         delivery_mode = 2, # make message persistent
                      ))
print(" [x] Sent %r" % message)
connection.close()
```

I've created two users on both hosts with command:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl add_user login-to-remote pass
```

And when i trying to run anything i've got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "worker.py", line 5, in <module>
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=NEW_TASK_HOST_IP, socket_timeout=300, credentials=credentials))
  File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 414, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 466, in _flush_output
    raise maybe_exception
pika.exceptions.ProbableAccessDeniedError: (-1, "error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')")
```

I've checked the connection between host with `iperf` for both udp and tcp in both directions:

```
iperf -s -p 5672
iperf -p 5672 -c 192.168.0.2
```

So the traffic goes.

I'am complitly stack, what can be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
                    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='new-task-host-ip'))

.
.
.

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
    host='worker-ip', socket_timeout=300, credentials=credentials))
```

`'new-task-host-ip'` and `'worker-ip'` are invalid IP addresses. You need to replace these with the actual IP address of the host (presumably `'localhost'` or `'127.0.0.1`).

Comment: Yes, this is just example, of course there are real ip instead of those strings, i'll change this string by IPs for clarity

Comment: @Kirill Then this question becomes about networks and not programming. Check the firewall settings, port forwarding if relevant, etc.

Comment: I've checked connection with iperf for RabbitMQ ports, everything is fine.